# Need a help for upload csv

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, file-upload, csv

I have a csv file with 9 lacks data(size of csv file is 229mb).I split the csv file in smaller ie, one csv contains 4000 or 5000 data.I  upload the csv file and read data from it and insert it into database.1st I insert the data in to a dummy table and list it.Then submit the list and insert in to the main table.But it takes more than 1hr.My code is,

```
$path = "csv1.csv";
if (($handle = fopen("$path", "r")) !== FALSE) {
$cntcnt=1;
   while (($info = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      foreach($info as $key=>$value) {
      $datas[$key]=$value;
                             if(isset($datas[3]))       $bname      = $datas[3];        else $bname     = "";
                            if(isset($datas[4]))        $address    = $datas[4];        else $address       = "";
                            if(isset($datas[5]))        $city       = $datas[5];        else $city          = "";
                            if(isset($datas[7]))        $zipcode    = $datas[7];        else $zipcode       = "";
                            if(isset($datas[8]))        $cname      = $datas[8];        else $cname         = "";
                            if(isset($datas[13]))       $phone      = $datas[13];       else $phone             = "";
                            if(isset($datas[14]))       $fax        = $datas[14];       else $fax           = "";
                            if(isset($datas[15]))       $email      = $datas[15];       else $email         = "";
                            if(isset($datas[16]))       $website    = $datas[16];       else $website           = "";
                            $bname= mysql_real_escape_string($bname); 
                            $cname= mysql_real_escape_string($cname);
                            $address =mysql_real_escape_string($address);
                            $city =mysql_real_escape_string($city);
$data=array('vendorid'=>$vendorid,'cid'=>$cid,'scid'=>$scid,'sscid'=>$sscid,'rid'=>$rid,'pid'=>$pid,'rcid'=>$cityid,'lid'=>$lid,'bname'=>$bname,'address'=>$address,'street'=>$street,'zipcode'=>$zipcode,'phone'=>$phone,'cell'=>$cell,'fax'=>$fax,'email'=>$email,'website'=>$website,'description'=>$description,'mapaddress'=>$mapaddress,'price'=>$price,'date'=>$date,'ref_code'=>$ref_code,'realestate_category'=>$realestate_category,'template'=>$template,'busname'=>$busname,'code'=>$code,'b_type'=>$b_type,'edit_date'=>$edit_date,'phone2'=>$phone2,'cname'=>$cname,'ssscid'=>$ssscid);
$this->db->insert('c_tbldummy',$data);
        }
        }
```

Is there any way to speed up this process?Because my client wants to upload 50000 to 75000 data.Any one please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE its more faster to upload and also add index to your table

here sample of LOAD DATA INFILE

Code:

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$path_of_csv_file' INTO TABLE $table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES ($column_of_table);
```

you can add "set" for columns that are not in csv

Code:

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$path_of_csv_file' INTO TABLE $table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES ($column_of_table) set column1 = '$value1', column2= '$value2' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

using batch_insert should reduce your time...

```
$this->db->insert_batch();
```

here, you are inserting each row's data  in a table... so since you have 75000 + datas ..that means 75000+ insert query.. which i guess is taking time.... this may not speed up noticebly but i am sure this will reduce the taken time to insert..

batch insert will reduce the query to one.. and inserts all your datas in one query..

you can give it a try...

```
 while (($info = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  foreach($info as $key=>$value) {
  $datas[$key]=$value;
                         if(isset($datas[3]))       $bname      = $datas[3];        else $bname     = "";
                        if(isset($datas[4]))        $address    = $datas[4];        else $address       = "";
                        if(isset($datas[5]))        $city       = $datas[5];        else $city          = "";
                        if(isset($datas[7]))        $zipcode    = $datas[7];        else $zipcode       = "";
                        if(isset($datas[8]))        $cname      = $datas[8];        else $cname         = "";
                        if(isset($datas[13]))       $phone      = $datas[13];       else $phone             = "";
                        if(isset($datas[14]))       $fax        = $datas[14];       else $fax           = "";
                        if(isset($datas[15]))       $email      = $datas[15];       else $email         = "";
                        if(isset($datas[16]))       $website    = $datas[16];       else $website           = "";
                        $bname= mysql_real_escape_string($bname); 
                        $cname= mysql_real_escape_string($cname);
                        $address =mysql_real_escape_string($address);
                        $city =mysql_real_escape_string($city);
               $data[]=array('vendorid'=>$vendorid,'cid'=>$cid,'scid'=>$scid,'sscid'=>$sscid,'rid'=>$rid,'pid'=>$pid,'rcid'=>$cityid,'lid'=>$lid,'bname'=>$bname,'address'=>$address,'street'=>$street,'zipcode'=>$zipcode,'phone'=>$phone,'cell'=>$cell,'fax'=>$fax,'email'=>$email,'website'=>$website,'description'=>$description,'mapaddress'=>$mapaddress,'price'=>$price,'date'=>$date,'ref_code'=>$ref_code,'realestate_category'=>$realestate_category,'template'=>$template,'busname'=>$busname,'code'=>$code,'b_type'=>$b_type,'edit_date'=>$edit_date,'phone2'=>$phone2,'cname'=>$cname,'ssscid'=>$ssscid);

    }
    }

$this->db->insert_batch('c_tbldummy',$data);
```

[CI doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) for insert_batch()